# Registration Form (HTML, PHP & MySQL) redirect after error or missing values

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I am  new to development with HTML, PHP, CSS etc.

I need to do this small Registration and Login Form. I haven't gone into detail in Object-Oriented PHP and I'm working in the simplest manner as this task needs to be done in a short time and I've only been coding and experimenting with these languages these past two days.

What I already have is a working Registration and Login forms that when they are submitted the information is posted to another php file. Than it verifies that the data has been entered and that the e-mail isn't already used.  What i need is that when either the e-mail is already used and when a field is left empty that it automatically goes back to Registration/Login forms and displays a message with their respective errors.

I know this might have been done in a different way but the deadline is really close and so i need a solution that works with what I already have.

I'm sorry if a similar question is already available, but i might be using incorrect keywords to search for the solution.

Keywords currently that I'm using are Redirection, "Going back to previous page".

If JavaScript is more suitable for this kind of operation it is also excepted and would like this to be pointed out, although a php solution would be appreciated a bit more as i currently obtain more knowledge on PHP than on JavaScript.

Thanks, any help or directions to suitable solutions would be mostly appreciated.

Comment: in php..you can use header('Location: login.php'); to redirect one page to another.

Comment: Ok, that I found information about but can I send information the the login.php for example just a number that differentiates between one error and another and than the login.php displays a message to the user accordingly?

Comment: you can send something like  header('Location: login.php?error=101'); you can catch error using $_GET, evaluate in if-else and echo some message.

Comment: I tried this, it's not working well till now, it's telling me that the Object is not found!

Comment: can you post some codes so that i can give a solution? maybe codes where those error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to do this. If when the form is submitted your executing the code on a  different php file then you could have an IF statement there which redirects the headers back to the form page if there are errors with the users input such as:

```
if($username == "")
{
    header("Location: YOUR_FORM_PAGE.php");
}
```

Hope this helps.

To add the execution to the same page you can do this.

add these buttons;

```
<input type="hidden" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="1">
<span class="label"></span><input type="submit" class="submit"  value="Submit"><input type="reset" class="submit"  value="Clear">
```

set the form action to the form page. Add this to the top of the page and add any PHP you want to it;

```
if(isset($_POST["submitted"]) && $_POST["submitted"] == 1)
{
```

for example;

```
if($from_fullname == "")
    {
        $submission_status = '<div class="vpb_info" align="left">Please enter your fullname in the required field to proceed. Thanks.</div>';
    }
```

and add this to the page where you want the error displayed;

```
 <p> <?php echo $submission_status; ?></p>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks yes that's good but could this send a sign the the YOUR_FORM_PAGE.php that it had an error, and than the error is displayed in the YOUR_FORM_PAGE.php ?

Comment: the best way to perform this simply would be to redirect the user to the same form page when they submit, this can be done by having a hidden submit button on your page set to value = 1, then the form action set to the form page and then add PHP to the top of your php form starting with "if(isset($_POST["submitted"]) && $_POST["submitted"] == 1)" then you can have any error messages displayed from their.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- A) [PHP header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
- B) echo a META HTTP - EQUIV=" refresh "
  CONTENT=" seconds; URL =    \the-other-url">
- C) Use JS like [this](http://www.essex1.com/people/timothy/js-trn2n.htm) but you
  will need to set a timeout

Example:

```
if (empty ($_POST ['username']) || empty ($_POST ['password']))
{
    echo "Please enter a username, or password";
    header ("refresh:5; url=back.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I don't think C applies as what i need is that once the register or login forms are submited, taken to the next php which displays nothing unless everything is validated (every field is filled and email isn't already in use). Option A i had already seen the link you've given me but honestly i didn't understand how it works exactly what it those. The part I didn't understand is the  [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] ) part could you show me a small example?

Comment: on your other php script once you do the validation you will use option A if the validation fails.. I think, that you dont know how to validate the user... if this is correct your better of posting your code here.

Comment: Updated post, please try it out if you can.

Comment: Yes, i will thanks. If you are talking about JavaScript Validation no i don't know how to. The validation i have done is done in a very primitive manner.

Comment: No, I mean php, yet you can use JS.

Comment: Sorry, the reason why i said that is that i have seen a validation done by javascript and so associated Validation to javascript as i thought it might be the best tool for it (as the website was very professional).

Comment: its ok :), hope you get this going.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `http-redirect` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php) should help you out. You can redirect on your error conditions with that.

**Update**

With redirect you can attatch QueryString Parameters so you could redirect back to the login.php page with an errror code and/or message as a query string perameter.

Answer (score 0):

These will get you started, a registration or signup php file and a login php file I made once
(personal info is faked).

SignUp.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$userpassword = hash('sha512',$_REQUEST['password'] );
$signature = $_REQUEST['signature'] ;
$image = $_REQUEST['image'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$emailreplies = $_REQUEST['emailreplies'] ;




if (!isset($_REQUEST['name'])) {
    header( "Location: MotesBlog.php" );
}else{

$username="root";
$password="root";
$database="MotesBlog";

mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    $query=sprintf("SELECT Name FROM users WHERE Name LIKE '%s';",
                   mysql_real_escape_string($name));
    $query=mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)){

        $query = sprintf("SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Name='%s';",
                                 mysql_real_escape_string($name));
        $query=mysql_query($query);

        $_SESSION['NameTaken'] = true;
        $_SESSION['UsedName'] = $name;
        $_SESSION['UsedEmail'] = mysql_result($query,0);
        header("Location: SignUp.html");
    }else{

    $query=sprintf("SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Email LIKE '%s';",
                   mysql_real_escape_string($email));
    $query=mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)){

        $_SESSION['EmailTaken'] = true;
        $_SESSION['UsedEmail'] = $email;
        header("Location: SignUp.html");
    }else{

        $query = sprintf(" INSERT INTO users VALUES (
        NULL , '%s', '%s' , '%s', '%s', '%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 0, $emailreplies);",
        mysql_real_escape_string($name),
        $userpassword,
        mysql_real_escape_string($signature),
        mysql_real_escape_string($image),
        mysql_real_escape_string($email));

        mysql_query($query);


        $query = sprintf("SELECT JoinDate FROM users WHERE Name='%s';",
                         mysql_real_escape_string($name));

        $vcode=md5(mysql_result(mysql_query($query),0));

        mysql_close();


        require_once "Mail.php";

        $from = "PocketWoods Hunting Hall<pwoods@email.com>";
        $to = $email;
        $subject = "Welcome to Motes Blog";
        $body = "<html>
                 <body>Thank you for your time. <br/>
                 To ensure a human made this account and not an 
                 automated process please click the link below:<br>
                 <a href=\"http://site.com/MotesBlog/verifyaccount.php?vcode=".$vcode."&name=".$name."\">
                 Activate Account
                 </a>
                 </body>
                 </html>";  

        $host = "mail.root.com";
        $username = "root@root.com";
        $password = "root";

        $headers = array (  'From' => $from,
                            'To' => $to,
                            'Subject' => $subject,
                            'MIME-Version' => "1.0",
                            'Content-type' => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                array ( 'host' => $host,
                        'auth' => false,
                        'username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password));

        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


        header("Location: success.html");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php

session_start();



$username="root";
$password="root";
$database="MotesBlog";

mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$user_name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$user_password = $_REQUEST['password'];

if (!isset($_REQUEST['name'])) {
    header( "Location: MotesBlog.php" );
}else{

    if(isset($_SESSION['User'])){
        if( ($_SESSION['CreatedTime'] + 3600) < time() ){

            $_SESSION['Expired'] = true;
        }
        unset($_SESSION['User']);
    }




    $query = sprintf("SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Name='%s';",
    mysql_real_escape_string($user_name));
    $query=mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
        $real_password=mysql_result($query,0);

        $query = sprintf("SELECT Email FROM users WHERE Name='%s';",
        mysql_real_escape_string($user_name));

        $query=mysql_query($query);
        $email = mysql_result($query,0);

        if($real_password == hash('sha512',$user_password)){



            $query = sprintf("SELECT Validated FROM users WHERE Name='%s';",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user_name));
            $query=mysql_query($query);

            mysql_close();

                if(mysql_result($query,0)){

                    $_SESSION['User'] = $user_name;
                    $_SESSION['CreatedTime'] = time();
                    setcookie("User", $_REQUEST['name'], time() + 60*60*24*365);

                    header( "Location: MotesBlog.php" );

                }else{

                    $_SESSION['resend_name'] = $user_name;
                    $_SESSION['resend_email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['NotValidated'] = true;

                    header( "Location: MotesBlog.php" );

                    }
            }else{

                $_SESSION['WrongPW'] = true;
                $_SESSION['UsedEmail'] = $email;
                header( "Location: MotesBlog.php" );
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['WrongName'] = true;
            header( "Location: MotesBlog.php" );
        }


}

?>
```